# How to filter SNS message sent by Elasticache?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-elasticache

I need to monitor an Elasticache replication group with SNS + Pagerduty.
Problem is Elasticache sends all events to configured sns arn without differentiating whether it's a serious event like ElastiCache:SnapshotFailed or a normal one as ElastiCache:CacheClusterParametersChanged.

I tried to attach a filter policy to the subscription of the topic, unfortunately the the filtering only works for message which contains a 
 "MessageAttributes" field as mentioned in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/message-filtering.html. So it doesn't work for me.

The message send by Elasticache is like:

```js
{
  "Type" : "Notification",
  "MessageId" : "93cc4ffe-bbd7-521e-8dd1-1c25d437dc1b",
  "TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:custid:redis-monitor-a",
  "Message" : "{\"ElastiCache:SnapshotComplete\":\"redis-a-001\"}",
  "Timestamp" : "2018-08-01T08:21:52.610Z",
  "SignatureVersion" : "1",
  "Signature" : "aaabbbccc",
  "SigningCertURL" : "xxxbbbzzz",
  "UnsubscribeURL" : "yyyzzzaaa"
}
```

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I end up filtering those events from Pagerduty side, by using event rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you correctly pointed out SNS message filtering works based on message attributes.

So basically if elasticache is not setting any MessageAttributes then message filtering cannot be done

The only option left with you is to read the messages in the subscribers and then ignore the ones that you don't want

Comment: Cool, I wish they did provide a more generic filtering mechanism.

Comment: I think a more feasible option for AWS  is that elasticache populates the message category in the message attribute that it dumps to sns

Answer (score 2):

For those who are coming to this like me, in 2023, it is now possible to filter out elasticache events

You can now set a Subscription filter policy to have a filter policy scope of `Message body` and you can set the policy to be something like this

```
{
  "ElastiCache:SnapshotComplete": [
    {
      "exists": false
    }
  ]
}
```

This will filter out all events that have the "ElastiCache:SnapshotComplete" in its message body

if you are using terraform, it is something like this

```
resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "sns_subscription" {
  filter_policy = jsonencode({
    "ElastiCache:SnapshotComplete" = [{ "exists" : false }]
  })
  filter_policy_scope = "MessageBody"
}
```